# File uploading only working with some images (class.upload.php)

Tags: php, image-uploading

I've tried the native way of uploading images with PHP, but my friend suggested me to the class.upload.php library, which still had the same results as before.  I can only upload certain images without them having that little icon that means that the browser can't find the image, but what's weird is that when I download the "invalid" images to my computer, they're fine.  About 50% of images actually do work, but the rest just show the appropriate size that they should have but no image.  Here is my code (my html form has a file input type called `filename`:

```
$handle = new upload($_FILES['filename']);

if ($handle->uploaded)   
{
   if ($file_src_size < 20000)
   {
        $handle->file_new_name_body = "test";  
        $handle->image_convert = 'jpg';
        $handle->process('/');  

        echo "<img src = \"test.jpg\" />";
    }
    else echo "Files must be 20 kb or under";
}
else echo "Upload failed, please try again";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can download the images and re-display locally them suggests that the problem is not with the upload script.  An alternative problem could be that the images are not properly saved for web viewing. For example, just because a file ends in .jpg and can be viewed locally does not mean that it is recognizable by a browser. A CMYK jpeg cannot be viewed by many browsers.

Comment: What are some solutions to this?

Comment: You can use an image editor to open the images that are not web compatible, and then save them in a web compatible format. I use Photoshop myself which has an "export for web" command that handles the version automatically. In my experience, most images that have this issue are CMYK jpg files, and most any image editor could cpnvert them to RGB format. But you didn't say what type of images they are, and there are many, many formats a browser will not view.

Comment: But could I automate that so that it's exported to web after uploading?

Comment: Ah, no, sorry for the confusion. All the tools I mentioned require processing of the image on your side, before the upload. To do it after upload you would need to look for some kind of php-based image processor. I imagine such tools exist, but I do not know of one myself.

Comment: "What are some solutions to this?"

I suggest either putting an link online to a 'broken' image so that other people can investigate it for you, or to just debug it by looking at the data being transferred (by monitoring the HTTP connection with Wireshark) and just figuring what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code as something is going wrong, and only someone with access to your computer can tell you why.

1) The library you're using has error detection code

```
if ($handle->processed) {
       echo 'image resized';
       $handle->clean();
} else {
   echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
}
```

2) You should be able to look at the processed image data, and figure out why the browser is not able to parse it as an image. If you can give a URL for an invalid image I would be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

3) Writing files to the root directory by calling "process('/');" is bad. You should make a directory to hold files that come from other people, to avoid having potential problems when some uploads an image called 'index.php'.

Comment: I'm not actually processing to the root directory--it was to keep the question simpler.