# PHP-based image processor that can be fed uploaded images?

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there some kind of software that I can feed uploaded images to and have it process them to give back to me? This question is based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940527/file-uploading-only-working-with-some-images-class-upload-php) question, where one of the answerers told me to use some kind of processor that I could feed images to, but he did not know one that was good.  Are there any programs like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) built in. Check out some of the functions in that link. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: How exactly would I use GD in this example?

Answer (score 0):

As Jebego said, [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is good and will do almost all of what you could possibly need.

And [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) does everything that you could possibly need, but is slightly harder to use.

However I think the answer to your other question is bogus, and possibly leading you down the wrong path.

Comment: How exactly would I use GD in this case? I have a little bit of experience with it, but how would it help here?

Comment: "how would it help here"
"However I think the answer to your other question is bogus, and possibly leading you down the wrong path."